# python pandas identify word which has highest value in data frame from list of given words

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, and a list of values.  Of the words in my list, I want to find which one has the highest value in my DataFrame.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
     words  sum
284   call   85
937     im   55
2158    ur   41
762    get   40
779     go   37
1098  like   37
1342   now   36
1998  text   36
717   free   35
543   dont   34
1369    ok   31
2045  time   31
```

Here is my list:

```
syy = ['get', 'go', 'like']
```

I want output to be word "get" because it has highest value in data frame

Comment: Highest value in what column? `sum` ? Because `get` does not have the largest value....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'words': ['call', 'im', 'ur', 'get', 'go', 'like', 'now', 'text', 'free', 'dont', 'ok', 'time'],
    'sum': [85, 55, 41, 40, 37, 37, 36, 36, 35, 34, 31, 31]},
    index=[284, 937, 2158, 762, 779, 1098, 1342, 1998, 717, 543, 1369, 2045]
)

syy = ['get', 'go', 'like']
```

---

Filter using `isin` then use `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df[df.words.isin(syy)]['sum'].idxmax(), 'words']
```

```
'get'
```

---

***Explanation***

First, find the rows that match your list:

```
df[df.words.isin(syy)]
```

```
     words  sum
762    get   40
779     go   37
1098  like   37
```

Next, find the maximum value of `sum` from this collection:

```
df[df.words.isin(syy)]['sum'].idxmax()
```

```
 762
```

Finally, find the value of `words` for that row:

```
df.loc[df[df.words.isin(syy)]['sum'].idxmax(), 'words']
```